# GridView Adapter inflates the wrong position of the ArrayList on Scroll

Tags: java, android, android-layout, gridview

I'm trying to create a Like/Unlike button for my GridView and I added a onClickListener to the button via my Custom GridView Adapter. However I noticed something weird. The adapter reads the position of the arraylist item below the one that is being displayed currently, thus sending a wrong id to my Mobile Backend. The wrong item gets 'liked'.

The root of this problem was that, **when the user is in between two arraylist items in the GridView**, the adapter gets the position of the second item instead of the 1st item. **So therefore when I click on the like button of the 1st item, the second item gets liked because that's the position the adapter reads.**

How can I make sure that an item can be 'liked' even when they aren't fully 'in view'.

To further explain:

**THIS will properly 'like' the currently displayed newsfeed item**

[image]

**THIS will 'like' the SECOND item since its partially in view**

[image]

Here's a code snippet of the array list and the selection of the position:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi = convertView;
        final ActivityTable act = actList.get(position);
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_single_picture, null);

         holder.likebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
                 //Send like
           }

           //More code
          return vi;
    }

   public static class Holder {
      ImageButton likebtn;
   }
```

I believe it's not something wrong with the code. It's the way android works? How do I get around it?

This is a major problem, since the user can't hit the like button of an item without being in full view of it. How can I avoid this blunder?

Comment: I asked a theory question. I cannot provide the entire Adapter code, can I? Why does this question have a down vote?

Comment: please add the adapter code...atleast part where you are setting listener and views

Comment: Depending on how much the entire Adapter is, you can indeed. At least the part that handels the clicks on the like buttons would be helpfull to actually know whats wrong.
But other than missing some code, ther's nothing wrong with your question, I don't get the downvote either.

Comment: @Gumbo Added the code

Comment: @ShadowDroid Added the code

Comment: I don't think so because I have added that in my code , and its works fine , can you please add , a normal check for getting position of click onGrid View.

Comment: Still not very informative. In the onClickListener, how exactly do you find out the index of the button that was clicked?

Comment: I am not looking for an index mate, I'm just getting the item at the arraylist's position and then passing it through the 'like method'. Am I supposed to get the index of the button? :O @Gumbo

Comment: @Earthling Call it an index or a position, I mean you probably take the buttons position/index and get the ID to send to the server from some kind of data set (ArrayList or something) I suppose that's where the off-by-one error happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is how you have implemented viewholder pattern then please change your getView method to

```
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

      View vi = convertView;
      final ActivityTable act = actList.get(position);
      Holder holder;
      if (vi == null) {
       vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_single_picture, null, false);
       holder = new Holder();
       holder.likebtn = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
       vi .setTag(holder); // setting Holder as arbitrary object for row
      } else { // view recycling
       // row already contains Holder object
       holder = (Holder) vi .getTag();
     }



      holder.likebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
                 //Send like
                   **here you can check the position**
           }

           //More code
          return vi;
    }
```

What I see from your implementation is that you are inflating view again and again every time getView was called for each position. On the other hand a **ViewHolder object** stores each of the component views inside the tag field of the Layout, so you can immediately access them without the need to look them up repeatedly. 
Also the listener will be properly attached...bcoz your implementation had a static image button to which listener was attached that took items based on the position visible.

Comment: I see. What does this do, mate? Can you explain a bit, I'd love to understand the concept

Comment: Btw I got 2 duplicates when I tried your solution. The same item repeated twice in the beginning. The rest were okay

Comment: I get so many duplicate items in the GridView with this solution you gave me. Why is that?

Comment: make sure you don't have duplicate items in your list..now related to original problem are sure the click on like button is properly reflected

Comment: No duplicates in the list mate. The solution added a couple of duplicates.. yes the on click works but it gave me another problem to worry about haha

Comment: I am sure this way of implementation should not add duplicates because it is standard practice for view holder pattern for smooth scrolling of list which is suggested here -http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html